# Unable to download .xlsx file in the response of api call in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to download '.xlsx' file from the response of the api call in angular 2. In response body am getting the data as xml format. It is downloading but after opening the file it gives error like corrupted file. Please find below sample code.

```
this.homeDetailViewService.downloadReport(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
            .subscribe((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
                    let blob = new Blob([response._body],{type:contentType});
                    let link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.download = "report.xlsx";
                    link.click();
                 }
            },
            (error) => {


                let errorObj = JSON.parse(error);
                // If theres no data then reset the model list and total
                if (errorObj.status === "error" && errorObj.message.match(/Record not found/)) {
                    this.curData = null;
                }
                this.loadingAnimation = false;                    // error path
                this.handleError(error);
            },
            () => {// onComplete                                           
            });
```

In `response._body` am getting data like below

[image]

So i don't know how to download xml type response body into '.xlsx' format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now.

I added `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` in the request object.

And import `ResponseContentType` to the service file before use as below.

```
import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
```

After this no "Corrupt file error" is showing and excel file data coming fine.